# Delete an access file row via DataGrid

Tags: c#, database, datagrid

I'm currently learning to delete and update files into an access database (mdb). 
But i encountered an error which i'm not able to solve.

My database consists of 6 columns. The relevant columns for now are "ID" and "Date". ID is a textfield with an autoincrement primary key and date an ordinary text field (dd.MM.yyyy).

I can delete rows by selecting an ID just fine. (The selecting is done by putting the ID into a textfield)

Now i wanted to get rid of the whole ID since i don't really need it in the database itself and wanted to select the rows by the actual Date (which only exists once). 
But if i try to select by date i encounter a

> Syntaxerror in number in query expression 'Date =29.10.201'

I'm not sure why the 2015 gets shortened so instead of using "dateTimePicker1.Text" i converted the dateTimePicker value to string and split it, then returned only the Date but it gets the same error.

Here is the code i used for the split:

```
string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString().Split(' ')[0];
con.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Command.Text = "delete from " + user + " where Date =" + date + " ";
command.ExecuteNonQuery;
con.Close();
```

And here is the code i used before

```
command.Command.Text = "delete from " + user + " where Date =" + dateTimePicker1.Text + " ";
```

Thanks in advance for every answer. :)

Comment: so when you use the debugger what is the value of `datee` when you step past this line `string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString().Split(' ')[0];` also why don't you just capture the value of the DateTimePicker and convert that datetime value to a formatted date without the time.. ? as a string value..

Comment: change your string date to the following 
`var date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();` or 
do this 
`var date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");`

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks for your answer. If i give the value to a textbox i get the actual date (29.10.2015 with the Split). 
The converted datetime value (as suggested by you after that) gives the same error unfortunately....

Comment: look at the date value and ask yourself what the date format is in the database.. is it yyyy-MM-dd format, dd-MM-yyyy what is the datatype of the field you are trying to update.. your command should be the following 
`command.Command.Text = "delete from user  where Date = " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");`

Comment: and if you are getting the date as `29.10.2015` are the dates stored in the database with `.` in them..? if not then use the replace function at the end of the `.ToString()` method like this `.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy").Replace(".","-");`

Comment: @MethodMan yes the dates are stored with a "." in the database. To ensure i also switched the save code with your "ToShortDateString" and tried it with that as well. 
It's the same error...somehow the last number always get's shortened. Be it a year or day when reversing the date. 
If i do replace the "." with "-" however, i don't get an error but the code doesn't execute anything either....just runs on without changing/deleting. :D

Comment: then change the format in the string to be `.` and not `-`

Comment: @MethodMan - sorry it's quite late for me here maybe i'm too confused but the format in the string is already "." and not "-" or it wouldn't be stored in the database as "." or am i missing something...? :(

Comment: I think you are not understanding the code I have shown.. maybe you should sleep on it and wake up with a fresh mind.. have a good night

Comment: @MethodMan hello again - after a good nights sleep i tried again to get my head around your answers but i didn't really seem to understood. 
Could you maybe specify what you meant for me? 
I'm pretty new to coding (in my second month actually) and am grateful for every opportunity to learn/get something explained.

Answer (score 0):

A literal date needs to be escaped just like a string i.e. `... WHERE Date = '2015-10-29'`.  Ensure the format of the date in your SQL command as well.

Have you inspected `command.Command.Text` before you call `ExecuteNonQuery` ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you mean the format of the date in the database? (Where it's saved as textfield) or in c#?